# javaScript lose focus when I append <embed>

Tags: javascript, jquery, focus, embed, beep

I need to add beep in my script. I add  every time, when sound must be.

```
$("#beep").html("<embed src='button-16.wav' hidden='true' autostart='true' loop='false' id='bp' />")
```

But when I add , my  lost focus.

I tried to focus it again in the following ways.

1)

```
$("#beep").html("<embed src='button-16.wav' hidden='true' autostart='true' loop='false' id='bp' />");
$("#txt").focus();
```

2)

```
$("#beep").html("<embed src='button-16.wav' hidden='true' autostart='true' loop='false' id='bp' />");
$("#bp").ready(function(){
    $("#txt").focus(); 
});
```

But neither first nor second way works.

HTML code.

```
<div id="beep"></div>
<input type="text" id="txt" />
```

So, how can I save focus of textbox after beep?

Comment: You should use HTML5 `<audio>` instead...

Comment: Unfortunately, there is a lot of old brouser without HTML5...

Comment: Recent browsers support it though. Giving those using an ancient browser a reason to upgrade isn't bad..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found quite different way to solve this problem.
I've wrote *.swf, which play a beep, when JavaScript call its function.

ActionScript code.

```
package  {
import flash.display.*;
import flash.events.*;
import flash.system.*;
import flash.media.Sound;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.external.ExternalInterface;

public class Main extends Sprite {
    var s:Sound;
    public function Main() 
    {
        ExternalInterface.addCallback("PlaySound", PlaySound);
        var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("beep.mp3");
        s = new Sound(request);
    }
    public function PlaySound():void
    {
        s.play();
    }
}
}
```

JavaScript code.

```
$("#txt").keyup(function(event){
    if(event.which==13){
     var obj=thisMovie("Main");
     obj.PlaySound();
    }
});

function thisMovie(movieName) {
var movie;
try
{
    movie = document[movieName];
    movie = (movie == null) ? window[movieName] : movie;        
}
catch (e)
{
    return null;
}
return movie;
}
```

Comment: It is important! Such code works only for a webserver, not for a local file system. I don't know, why. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5337071/externalinterface-addcallback-for-as3-doesnt-work

Answer (score 0):

can you try setting an interval to see if the end of the wav file is grabbing the focus?

```
setInterval(function() {
  $("#txt").focus(); 
}, 100);
```

I am only recommending this for troubleshooting purposes ... not as an actual fix. It might be taking longer to execute the .wav than it does to run the next process which is your focus()

Comment: I tried setTimeout(function(){$("#txt").focus();$("#subDebug").append("<p>Message</p>");},5000); I could hear beep, next text "Message" appeared in div #subDebug. But textbox didn't get focus again. Unfortunately, setInterval doesn't work, too - it executes every time (according to console.log), but $("#txt").focus(); doesn't focus the textbox.

Comment: I've added it. There are only 2 tags - div and input in html-file.